# Getting data from xml tag

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

How can I get text from a xml tag in Java?
For example this is the xml file:

```
<text data="word"/>
```

Here is my code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder=documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document=documentBuilder.parse(url);
            document.normalizeDocument();
            NodeList el=document.getElementsByTagName("data");
            System.out.println(el.getTextContent());
```

Comment: You should check out [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: @anaxin, Sorry, edited my post

Comment: your element's name is not data, it is text, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)
Download and add the jar file to your project. Then simply:

```
String html = "<text data=word />";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element element = document.select("text").first();
String str = element.attr("data");
System.out.println(str);
```

If you have multiple `<text>` tags you can get them all like this

```
Elements elements = document.select("text");
```